# CI: Authorize.net (or other?)

Tags: codeigniter, authorize.net, dpm

I'm looking for some guidance from those that may have integrated Authorize.net into a CI application (or any PHP MVC for that matter), and/or if there are other payment processing offerings you would suggest.

In particular, does anyone have examples/can point me in the right direction of implementing Authorize.net's DPM within an MVC PHP application?  My relay_response_url is set to a controller within my application, which is to then redirect it to a view for displaying the relevant success/error message(s).  But when I point DPM towards my controller, it errors out as I assume its expecting to immmediately put out a response, rather than being funneled thru?

Is DPM the solution to use?  Regardless, how should I capture the response from Auth.net in my controller and then pass it along to my view(s)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check out this payment library, as it will most likely simplify your life greatly...

http://getsparks.org/packages/codeigniter-payments/versions/HEAD/show